# Eagle create new package - set origin in PCB

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I'm creating a package with Eagle, an Arduino shield package. While placing the pads or even drawing tPlace symbol for the package, I feel very difficult to allocate these items.

If my memory works, there should be a command to set any arbitrary origin, then any placement would be calculated relatively to that origin. Is there such command in Eagle?

I could not find it nor even Google gives any good suggestion

Thank you!

Comment: I would love to know this, and how to place a component relative to current position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sigh...! it's been a while and no one has answered this. The other day, I did some searching and tried it well with "mark" command.

This command works in both schematic and layout window in Eagle. Topic closed! :D